# Create tabs swipe view failed

Tags: android, swipe, swipeview

How to fix `Main is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener` ?  Not sure whether I implementing in the correct method, but the debugger said  `import android.app.FragmentTransaction;` is unused statement.

I get the source from  [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/).

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction; // unused statement 


public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private TabsFragmentPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private ActionBar actionBar;
    // Tab titles
    private String[] tabs = {"Top Rated", "Games", "Movies"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        mAdapter = new TabsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Adding Tabs
        for (String tab_name : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                    .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

ActionBar.TabListener is an interface. So, if you implementing ActionBar.TabListener in your activity, you must implementing these method in your activity:

```
onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){}
onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){}
onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft){}
```

Ref: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.TabListener.html

Comment: but the tutorial did not implement the method

Comment: Just downloaded the source code, if you look closely, there are these method in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Add abstract in front of public

`public abstract class Main extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {`